# Compiling C# at Runtime

Tags: c#, runtime

I want to implement C# as the scripting language in my game.

My problem is, that my script will not compile if I want to use classes defined in the game core (exe).

The script looks like this:

```
using System;
using ConsoleApplication1;

class Script
{
private static void Call()
{
    Console.WriteLine("called");
}

public static void Init()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Script");
    Call();
    GameObject myO; // THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO GET WORKED,
 //IF THIS IS COMMENTED OUT, IT COMPILES FINE, GAMEOBJECT
 // IS DEFINED IN THE "ConsoleApplication1" NAMESPACE.
}
}
```

The script is compiled like in the MDX sample:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        //cp.CompilerOptions = "/target:library";
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
        cp.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("ConsoleApplication2.exe");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, "script.cs");
        if (!cr.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
            cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Script").GetMethod("Init").Invoke(null, null);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Is there any way to call functions or create objects defined in the "ConsoleApplication1" namespace via the script?

Comment: Did I miss the part where you state what compile time error you encounter?

Comment: Oh I´m so dumb... checked compiler error[0] and now it works, thanks

Comment: Is 'ConsoleApplication1.GameObject' defined in 'ConsoleApplication2.exe'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a daily programming problem.  It's not working and you think it should be working.  So break it down.  Instead of working on a big problem, work on a smaller problem.  Just tackle trying to compile the script **outside** of your program.  Once you get that working, then you can try to compile it as a script from inside your program, knowing that you've got the basic problem of references and compiler issues sorted out.

Something like:

> csc /reference:ConsoleApplication1.exe script.cs

From the looks of it, it might be as simple as changing the reference from `ConsoleApplication2.exe` to `ConsoleApplication1.exe`.